# Drop down combination

Tags: javascript

Hi all I am just a beginner in JavaScript. I tried to create a drop-down combination. But due to some reason this is not working.

This the html code:

```
<select id="MapSelect" onchange="changeChart();">
<option value="developmentRegionMap">Development Region</option>
<option value="ecoMap">Ecological Regions</option>
<option value="world_mill_en">Districts</option>
</select>


<select id="dataSelect" onchange="changeChart();">
<option value="CASTE1">CASTE1</option>
<option value="CASTE2">CASTE2</option>
</select>
```

This is the javascript portion;

```
    function changeChart() {
    var data={}
    var value = MapSelect.options[MapSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    var dataType = dataSelect.options[dataSelect.selectedIndex].value;

    if (value == "developmentRegionMap" && dataType == "CASTE1") {
            data=CASTE1_Developmental;
            alert("APPLE");
        }
    else if (value == "developmentRegionMap" && dataType == "CASTE2") {
            data=CASTE2_Developmental;
            alert("BALL");

        }

    else if (value == "ecoMap" && dataType == "CASTE1") {
            data=CASTE1_Eco;
            alert("CAT");
        }

    else if (value == "ecoMap" && dataType == "CASTE2") {
            data=CASTE2_Eco;
            alert("DOG");
        }

    else if (value == "world_mill_en" && dataType == "CASTE1") {
            data=CASTE1_Districts;
            alert("ELEPHANT");
        }

    else if (value == "world_mill_en" && dataType == "CASTE2") {
            data=CASTE2_CASTE2;
            alert("HEN");
    }

};
```

The jsfiddle  link to this code is:
http://jsfiddle.net/4yd2F/2/

Comment: What is probably is not working? How can You say it's not working? Maybe You could post some errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to physically retrieve the DOM objects you want to work with:

```
var mapSelect = document.getElementById('MapSelect');
var dataSelect = document.getElementById('dataSelect');
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/4yd2F/4/).

As Felix pointed out, what I suggested was not your main problem. The other issue is that you are not correctly using the `javascript` object type:

**Wrong:**

```
var data = {};
data = meh;
```

in this case `meh` is not a valid identifier since it was not defined as a variable nor is it a recognized identifier.

**Correct:**

```
data = {
    myString: 'hello',
    myArray: []
};
```

Comment: All major browsers generate global variables for elements with ID. While I personally don't like this, this is not the problem of the OP's code.

Comment: Wow, not often that I learn something new, thanks :). Ill update the answer to reflect the other problems

Answer (score 1):

Your jsFiddle demo doesn't work because

1. the `changeChart` function is not global, hence it cannot be called by the inline event handler (the console shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: changeChart is not defined`),
2. you are comparing `dataType` against different strings than `CASTE1` or `CASTE2`, none of the `if` conditions will ever be true,
3. many variables you are trying to access don't exist (e.g. `Brahmins_Developmental`, `Chhetri_Developmental`).

To solve this, you have to

1. Place the function definition directly in the head or body of the HTML document. In jsFiddle you can do this by selecting `No wrap - in <xyz>` in the settings.
2. Compare the value of the second dropdown against values that it actually has, i.e.  `CASTE1` and `CASTE2` (like you did in the code you posted here, but not in the demo).
3. Define the variables you want to use or don't use them.

---

Most of these things are easy to solve if you [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).